# Inline friend function defined in class body

Tags: c++

Normally when we define a member function directly in the class body, it is implicitly `inline`. But what about this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    friend void swap(Foo& a, Foo& b) { ... }

    ...
};
```

Is the `swap` implicitly `inline` or not?

Comment: I think it must be inline. Non-inline functionality can't go inside headers. Class bodies must be insertable inside headers. Ergo, all functionality provided inside class definition bodies must be inlinable functionality.

Comment: Is that even allowed? What does it mean to have a friend function defined inside the class body? Does it go into the enclosing namespace rather than being a member?

Comment: @jtbandes Yes. This defines a function in the same namespace as the class is in.

Comment: @jtbandes It's quite well explained in Johannes's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381164/friend-and-inline-method-whats-the-point .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  See [class.friend/6-7] from the Standard:

> A function can be defined in a friend declaration of a class if and only if the class is a non-local class (9.8), the function name is unqualified, and the function has namespace scope.
>
> Such a function is implicitly `inline`.