# How can I parse a char pointer string and put specific parts it in a map in C++?

Tags: c++, parsing, pointers, boost, hashmap

Lets say I have a char pointer like this:

```
const char* myS = "John 25 Lost Angeles";
```

I want to parse this string and put it in a hashmap, so I can retrieve the person's age and city based on his name only. Example:

```
std::map<string, string> myMap;

john_info = myMap.find("John");
```

How can I do this to return all of John's info in an elegant way ? I come from a Java background and I really want to know how this is properly done in C++. That would also be cool if you can show me how to do this using a boost map (if it is easier that way). Thank you.

Comment: Use `std::stringstream`. FYU `std::map` is not a hashmap.

Comment: what did you try? how would you do it in Java?

Comment: For a hash table, use `std::unordered_map`. That said, it looks like your question is about two things: parsing the string and storing the parsed string. I recommend removing the bit about hash maps and focussing the question on the parsing. I highly recommend making a `class` that aggregates the information and parsing the string into that object. Might be worth writing a [custom `operator >>` overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to show you one way to do it using Boost:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10e87b45c0e7267a)**

```
#include <map>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

using Name = std::string;
struct Details {
    unsigned age;
    std::string city;
};

using Map   = std::map<Name, Details>;
using Entry = Map::value_type;

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Details, age, city)

int main() {
    Map persons;

    std::string_view myS = //
        "John 25 Lost Angeles\n"
        "Agnes 22 Minion Appolis";

    auto name    = x3::lexeme[+x3::graph];
    auto age     = x3::uint_;
    auto city    = x3::raw[*(x3::char_ - x3::eol)];
    auto details = x3::rule<struct details_, Details>{} = age >> city;
    auto line    = name >> details;
    auto grammar = x3::skip(x3::blank)[line % x3::eol];

    if (x3::parse(myS.begin(), myS.end(), grammar, persons)) {
        for (auto& [name, details] : persons)
            std::cout << name << " has age " << details.age << "\n";
        for (auto& [name, details] : persons)
            std::cout << name << " lives in " << details.city << "\n";
    }

    // lookup:
    std::cout << "John was " << persons.at("John").age << " years old at the time of writing\n";
}
```

Prints

```
Agnes has age 22
John has age 25
Agnes lives in Minion Appolis
John lives in Lost Angeles
John was 25 years old at the time of writing
```

To use a hash-map, just replace

```
using Map   = std::map<Name, Details>;
```

with

```
using Map   = std::unordered_map<Name, Details>;
```

Now the output will be in implementation-defined order.

### CAVEAT

If this is home-work, please don't use this (kind of) approach. It will be very clear it was copy-pasted. Never use code you don't fully understand.

Comment: In the interest of overkill, I think the better representation would be a `Person { name, age, city }` struct that has several indices: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c456a9d2f8964e6c

Comment: Thanks man. This is not HW, but interview prepping. I appreciate it.

Comment: I guess for interview prepping the same caveat heavily applies. But I'd be thrilled to see someone write this code on an interview :)

Comment: For interview purposes, I ***bet*** they expect you to write standard-library only solutions, so e.g. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56fbd9c5e5eafbcd or http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86447e97201159d6

Comment: What does line 14 do ? The friend keyword is used. What does that do ?

Comment: @Saturnsbelt see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/382077/85371 (perhaps part 2 is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading#:~:text=std%3A%3Aistream%26%20operator%3E%3E(std%3A%3Aistream%26%20is%2C%20T%26%20obj))